# Scanning with %c or %s

Tags: c, arrays, char, scanf, format-specifiers

I had to do a program for college in which I should separate, between a certain amount of people, those who liked and the ones who disliked something.
so I did this:

```
    char like[100];

    printf("Like? Y or N \n");
    scanf ("%c", like);
```

The program compiled, but didn't work the way it should. The user was not able to write "y or n" when asked "Like?"

So I tried this:

```
    char like[100];

    printf("Like? Y or N \n");
    scanf ("%s", like);
```

And it worked. But I don't know why it worked. Can somebody please explain me the difference between `%c` and `%s` in a `scanf`?

Comment: Finding [this](http://www.codeforwin.in/2015/05/list-of-all-format-specifiers-in-c.html) took me all of about 10 seconds, please try and do some research before resorting to asking, it'll save you time too! :-)

Comment: `%s` skips leading whitespace characters, while `%c` does not. In your code, you had a trailing `\n` character prevailing in the standard input stream (`stdin`) left over by the previous `scanf`. `%s` skips over it, and waits for further non-whitespace input. `%c` consumes the `\n` and does not wait for further input.

Comment: "the programm compiled, but, didn't work the way it should." Why? What does "didn't work the way it should" mean? There's nothing wrong with the first program. Both of them will work. Each has its own peculiarities though.

Comment: Simple google search about format specifier might have given u better answer. Google and duck duck go are your friends

Comment: `%s` skips leading whitespace, and once scanning stops at whitespace, and writes a null terminator after the characters it scans.  `%c` does not skip whitespace, reads only one character unless a larger width is given, and doesn't write a null terminator.  The documentation (man page, etc.) explains this stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, please do some basic research before coming here - questions like this can usually be answered with a quick Google search or checking your handy C reference manual.

```
char inputChar;              // stores a single character
char inputString[100] = {0}; // stores a string up to 99 characters long

scanf( " %c", &inputChar );  // read the next non-whitespace character into inputChar
//            ^ Note & operator in expression
scanf( "%s", inputString );  // read the next *sequence* of non-whitespace characters into inputString
//           ^ Note no & operator in expression
```

You would use `%c` when you want to read a *single* character from the input stream and store it to a `char` object.  The `%c` conversion specifier will not skip over any leading whitespace, so if you want to read the next *non*-whitespace character, you need a blank before the `%c` specifier in your format string, as shown above.

You would use `%s` when you want to read a *sequence* of non-whitespace characters from the input stream and store them to an *array* of `char`.  Your target array must be large enough to store the input string *plus* a terminating 0-valued character.  The `%s` conversion specifier skips over any leading whitespace and stops reading at the first whitespace character following the non-whitespace characters.

Both `%c` and `%s` expect their corresponding argument to have type `char *` (pointer to `char`); however, in the first case, it's assumed that the pointer points to a single object, whereas in the second case, it's assumed that the pointer points to the first element of an array.  For `inputChar`, we must use the unary `&` operator to obtain the pointer value.  For `inputString`, we don't, because under most circumstances an *expression* of type "array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

Your code works fine as it is, but it's a bit confusing to read a single character and store it to an array.

Using `%s` without an explicit field width is risky; if someone types in more than 100 non-whitespace characters, `scanf` will happily store those extra characters to memory following `inputString`, potentially clobbering something important.  It's generally safer to write something like

```
scanf( "%99s", inputString ); // reads no more than 99 characters into inputString
```

or to use `fgets()` to read input strings instead:

```
fgets( inputString, sizeof inputString, stdin );
```

Please check §7.21.6.2 of the [online draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) of the C language standard for a complete description of all of the conversion specifiers for the `*scanf` functions.

Comment: Thanks man. I thought that, as i was expecting to recieve just simply 'y' or 'n' to fill my array, i should use my scanf with %c

Answer (score 0):

%s is used for string of characters and reads subsequent characters until it finds a whitespace(blank, newline or tab). Whereas %c is used for single character and reads the next character. If there are more than 1 character, including any whitespace character, it is read and stored in next iteration.